# QProcess not accepting arguments in MacOS

Tags: qprocess

Running Qt5.10 on MacOS 10.13.2

I am trying to open photoshop with one or more selected images in MacOS.  In terminal this works:

```
open "/Users/roryhill/Pictures/4K/2017-01-25_0030-Edit.jpg" -a "Adobe Photoshop CS6"
```

The following works in Windows but not MacOS:

```
QString app = "\"/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS6/Adobe Photoshop CS6.app\"";  // diff file path for windows
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "/Users/roryhill/Pictures/4K/2017-01-25_0030-Edit.jpg";
QProcess *process = new QProcess();
process->start(app, arguments);
```

In MacOS I get the error: "FailedToStart". 
If I drop the arguments in the last line and use:

```
process->start(app);
```

then photoshop opens.

I have also tried using the executable inside the app container:

```
"/Applications/Adobe Photoshop CS6/Adobe Photoshop CS6.app/Contents/MacOS/Adobe Photoshop CS6"
```

Again this works to open photoshop but fails when arguments are added.

This also fails:

```
process->setArguments(arguments);
process->setProgram(app);
process->start();
```

Omitting setArguments() fails too:

```
process->setProgram(app);
process->start();
```